# How to load local mutiplayer save game in Hammerwatch?

Tags: hammerwatch

I bought Hammerwatch and together with my friends, we managed to play local co-op for hours. I noticed that the game supports save-point, either by pressing the "floppy disk" tile inside the dungeon, or by traveling to another level (e.g. going up/down from current floor to another floor). Before ending our session, we confirmed that the game was saved by traveling to previous level.

Now, we wanted to continue our session, but we couldn't find it how. We have tried these:

1. Opening **Multi > Load** didn't show any save game.
2. Opening **Multi > Local** didn't show any indicator to load previous save game, and selecting **Level** only allows to select the campaign, but no save game.
3. Opening **Multi > Browse** seems only showing current available online sessions.

So, my question is, is the save system broken for local multiplayer? If it isn't, then how do we continue our previous local session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The save system is not broken for local multiplayer. The game really saves the session. However, to continue the local multiplayer session, you have to access the save file **from Single > Load**.

Even though the title reads "Load singleplayer game", it also lists your local multiplayer game. You can confirm it by seeing the number of the players on the game info on the right box when highlighting the save file. Clicking it will load the game and let you continue your local session.